# What is this UTC time format?

Tags: .net, xml, time, timezone, format

I am parsing an XML file that has a field called UTCTime and contains the value 1311346453064. It also comes with a field called UTC that contains the value 2011-07-22T10:54:13.064-04:00 which is a complete .Net DateTimeOffset I believe.  The first field I can't figure out though. What generates a date in that way? It's too large to be a unix timestamp since it adds about 41 millenia to 1/1/1970.  Any help in identifying it or how I can convert it to a datetime without using that second field would be a great help! Thanks.

Comment: That date is in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot) (ISO 8601 is actually quite flexible). I would post an answer, but I still don't know how to work with non-Local/non-UTC dates in .NET :( `DateTime.Parse` understands the format. ISO 8601 can represent dates not expressed in a 32-bit Unix epoch number -- and so can DateTime. See DateTime.MinValue and DateTime.MaxValue.

Comment: The other one is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, January 1st, 1970.  Make sure you hide under your desk when 2038 comes around.  The world will end, again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is equivalent to the unix timestamp [i.e. a straight count since 1970] but in milliseconds instead of seconds.

```
$ date -d @1311346453
Fri Jul 22 10:54:13 EDT 2011
```

Ending with `3064` made it obvious to me.

So, to convert in .NET you would use

```
static readonly DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,
                                              DateTimeKind.Utc);
long value = 1311346453064L;
var ts = new TimeSpan(value*TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
var dt = epoch + ts;
```

Or, slightly more efficiently at a cost of some readability

```
const long epochTicks = 621355968000000000L;
var dt = new TimeSpan(value*TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond+epochTicks,
                      DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Note that this discards the timezone information (the offset of `-04:00`) in the other field.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, that works!  I need to be more observant in the future I think, the ending does make a lot of sense looking back.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript example:

```
D:\ :: more > date.js
WScript.Echo( new Date().getTime() );
^Z

D:\ :: cscript date.js
1311975458665
```

This is the number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970.